# jest(createPortal) : container is not a DOM element

Tags: typescript, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-portal

I am testing my component using next.js.
However, when rendering the component, I found the following error:

I don't know how to approach the workaround.

Is there any way to fix it??

```
    Target container is not a DOM element.

  16 |   }, [selector]);
  17 |
> 18 |   return mounted ? createPortal(children, document.querySelector(selector) as HTMLParagraphElement) : null;   
     |                                ^
  19 | };
  20 |
  21 | export default Portal;
```

```js
//Portal.tsx
const Portal = ({ children, selector }: IProps) => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);

    return () => setMounted(false);
  }, [selector]);

  return mounted ? createPortal(children, document.querySelector(selector) as HTMLParagraphElement) : null;
};
```

```js
//target test component
const PeriodSettingWrapper = () => {
  const [showModalState, setshowModalState] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <PeriodSetting setshowModalState={setshowModalState} />
      <Portal selector="#portal">
        <ModalTemplate height={50} visibleState={showModalState} setVisible={setshowModalState}>
          <DatePickerModal />
        </ModalTemplate>
      </Portal>
    </>
  );
};
```

Here is my simple test code.

```js
describe('Period test', () => {
  test('must have to start date', () => {
    render(
      <RecoilRoot>
        <PeriodSettingWrapper />
      </RecoilRoot>
    );
    const text = screen.getByText('시작일');
    expect(text).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: You have to create an element that will match the `selector` you're using during your test. Otherwise `document.querySelector(selector)` will not return a valid DOM element.

Comment: @juliomalves Does that mean you have to render the modalTemplate component log in the render function as well? 
Or are you saying I need to add a tag like this <div id="portal" ... /> ?

Comment: _"I need to add a tag like this <div id="portal" ... />"_ - I meant this.